# Create speed baseline for local web file

Tags: page-speed, tools

Is there any tool or method that will load a localhost page a number of times, and return the averaged data for load times, onload events, Dom ready events, etc?

I'd like to work on page speed optimization, but need a baseline before I begin.

I have used both Google analytics and Webmaster tools, but I'd like an automated solutions that runs locally.

My ideal solution would be a program or script that would take the path/file, number of iterations, and then take several minutes to load the page n times without cache and crunch numbers to create a baseline.

Answer (score 1):

I've not heard of anything like what you're asking for, but it seems you could easily script one by checking your metrics and saving the data in the url. This would allow you to run locally or online without any changes.